# How do I login to a public Lotus Domino web application using social networks

Tags: facebook, oauth, lotus-domino, xpages

I have a public website created with xPages, My user are not logged to Domino (i.e anonymous) but I still want to display information for the users that is already logged in to facebook or twitter like the image or the users twitter stream and maybe let them be able to login to my site using fb/twitter so I can store some data about them for next visit.

I do not want to create users in any domino directory for this, but instead store the data I need in profiles/documents in the application. in this way I can store data from my users without the need to create new fields in domino directory.

To make it even simpler to understand. let's say I want to build a product site thay sell stuff using a domino application. When users enter the site they can choose to register with my application or login using e.g facebook or twitter. When they buy something or post a comment they are already logged in and do not need to enter user data. the user data come from social networks or the profile documents I have in my application.

Now off to some question...

- Can this be done easily using a domino application? or is it faster to
  build this using another platform?
- I do understand that I need to do some oAuth authentication to
  connect with twitter and facebook, but how do I connect this data to
  the profiles I have in my application?
- If users choose to register with my site instead of logging in to twitter/fb, how would I go about authenticating those users, and do I use different authentication depending on if they login using Twitter or using my profile documents.
- can I oAuth enable my Domino application?

/Thomas

Comment: I think you're asking too many very broad questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thomas, there was talk at Lotusphere 2012 about a Domino OAuth provider in a future Domino release.

Matt White wrote some SSO code for Facebook but this generates under the cover user accounts in the Domino Directory: http://mattwhite.me/blog/2010/10/20/how-to-get-sso-for-facebook-working-with-xpages.html

The XPages Social Enabler is the other direction. It allows writing XPages apps that access easily other OAuth services.

Comment: thank you Niklas, looks like something I could use

Answer (score 5):

Thomas,

You pressed the right button :)

I have worked on this a lot. I can share my results...

First, Social enabler cannot do this. Because current OAuth implementation is based on the assumption that user has a real identity inside Domino directory (because tokenstore is working by user name). Matt's solution is great if you want to put your user into a Domino directory.

I have started implementation for Twitter login without registering user. It will be an OpenNTF project. But it's going slow :(

There are two different things here in your question. Social Enabler has an OAuth client that allows to bind FB/Twitter user identification to a Domino User. It is not a 'login' in terms of your question.

On the other hand, to take advantage of Domino resources from an external application, we need a OAuth provider inside Domino server. Phil provided information about it at LS12. They will implement a provider and put it into OpenNTF soon. They have to do it in the future because otherwise, they can't use embedded activities effectively. So you may expect this will become a part of the product in an undefined future. But this has nothing to do with "Login by FB" architecture. That may be used to implement a Facebook application interacting with an XPages application.

The architecture for Login with FB would be like that. You will provide an OAuth dance between your app and Facebook, gather the user's FB identity and store it inside a 'Profile' store. That store may also be used to record user-specific information. At this point, you have three directions:

1. Import the user into a Domino directory (which is trusted via Directory assistance) and implement an authentication trick (look at the Matt's solution for this).
2. User may stay anonymous, but you would extend the user bean object to interact with him/her via this bean.
3. Create a LtpaToken to authenticate the user. I found how to do this. It should be implemented carefully and in fact user is not required to be registered in a trusted directory. But there are security risks and it should be handled carefully.

One more thing! It's also important to consider licensing! You need to use a proper licensing model for this (like XWork). It's not important which method you are using. Since you are identifying the user, it counts as authenticated user.

Hope this helps to create a draft direction for your project.

Comment: Thank you Serdar for your input, very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas,

I played with it a little bit, so I'm no expert, but I think the Java Library "Scribe" on github might help you do what you want.

Comment: I actually did look at scribe earlier, but run into some problems, not sure right now what it was. maybe it is just me having trouble understanding all these open source stuff that never seem to be documented in a generic way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

Creating LtpaToken is relatively easy way. If I know it needs a Java library (or porting it to LotusScript) that could be called from LotusScript and some configurations on Domino server. You can then exactly simulate what Domino is automatically doing during SSO authentication.

But remember what Serdar mentioned about licensing. The authenticated user should be still under a proper license.